Filter filtered bike prices twice without repeating yourself
dbfiddle
Goal
Without repetition in the code, I want to filter BikeValuationList to only give the BikePriceId of the latest valuation for the BikeID that I have. With this BikePriceId, I then wish to filter BikePrices for the corresponding row.
Schema
CREATE TABLE [BikePrices]
(
  [BikePriceId] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  [PrivateSalePrice] MONEY,
  [ShopPrice] MONEY
);

CREATE TABLE [BikeValuationList]
(
  [BikeID] INT,
  [ValuationCreatedDate] DATETIME,
  [BikePriceId] INT
);

Data
INSERT BikePrices
values (1, 1), (2, 2);

INSERT BikeValuationList
values (1, convert(datetime, '20240101'), 1), (1, convert(datetime, '20250101'), 2);

Code
DECLARE @MyBikeId INT = 1;

SELECT
    [BikePrices].*
FROM
    [BikePrices]
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [BikePriceId]
            ,[ValuationCreatedDate]
            ,MAX([ValuationCreatedDate]) OVER () [LastValuationDate]
        FROM
            [BikeValuationList]
        WHERE
            [BikeValuationList].[BikeID] = @MyBikeId        
    ) [BikeLookUp]
    WHERE
        [BikeLookUp].[BikePriceId] = [BikePrices].[BikePriceId]
    AND
        [BikeLookUp].[LastValuationDate] = [BikeLookUp].[ValuationCreatedDate]
);

Restrictions

Do not use a CTE. I have four reasons why they are not suitable in my case, but will not list them because they are not relevant here and will only cause arguments. I promise that it is nothing to do with performance.
I am extremely reluctant to repeat @MyBikeId or introduce new variables or temp tables.
Repetition must be minimised.

My Concerns
Was my solution any good? [LastValuationDate] and its usages are what cause me the most concern. It's not often that I see a semi-join used to filter a table based on its own columns, one of which is a window function's output.

Thank you for the Fiddle, that's very helpful.
primary key
In BikeValuationList you neglected to tell the backend
that BikeID is a Primary Key.
Every relation should have a PK.
foreign key
CREATE TABLE [BikeValuationList]
(
  ... ,
  ... ,
  [BikePriceId] INT

I don't understand that last line.
Wouldn't you like to offer some
DDL
that explains we have a FK relationship out to the BikePrices table?
singular table name
I'm not crazy about the container ...List suffix
of BikeValuationList, since an RDBMS table will always be a
container for multiple rows.
Recommend you just elide the suffix.
Similarly, consider renaming BikePrices
so it is simply the BikePrice relation.
capitalization
Wandering back and forth between FooID and FooId is distracting.
Please pick one approach and stick with it.
[identifiers]
You are in control of the identifiers you choose,
so you can avoid choosing SQL-92 reserved keywords,
or identifiers with embedded blanks and other troublesome
characters.
Rather than saying
SELECT [select]
FROM [select]

prefer
SELECT sensible_column_name
FROM sensible_table_name

without need to resort to SQL-92 " quoting
or vendor-specific [ ] quoting.
JOIN
I guess I just think about the problem differently from how you do.
Clearly the EXISTS approach works,
but it seems a little roundabout.
I definitely value having relations which describe items of interest
and which can be independently verified.
This lets us build toward a solution via composition.
Consider introducing this pair of sub-queries:
CREATE VIEW CurrentValuationTimestamp AS
SELECT BikeID, MAX(ValuationCreatedDate) AS ts
FROM BikeValuationList
GROUP BY BikeID;

CREATE VIEW CurrentValuation AS
SELECT V.*
FROM BikeValuationList V
JOIN CurrentValuationTimestamp TS
ON V.BikeID = TS.BikeID AND V.ValuationCreatedDate = TS.ts;

The first maps each bike to its relevant timestamp.
The second filters valuations down to just the relevant valuations.
With those in hand, obtaining the desired result rows becomes trivial.
SELECT P.*, V.BikeID, V.ValuationCreatedDate
FROM BikePrices P
JOIN CurrentValuation V  ON P.BikePriceId = V.BikePriceId
WHERE P.BikeID = @MyBikeId;

